# Can't access a class in different tab in Processing.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, tabs, processing

I am trying to create a class named Rocket in a tab named Rockets in Processing.py. No matter how I import the tab (`import Rockets`, `from Rockets import *`, `import Rockets as R`), I get:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Rocket'.

I tried putting the class definition in the same tab and it works fine so I think it's an import issue but I can't find my mistake.

Main tab:

```py
import Rockets

w_width = 800
w_height = 900
r1 = Rocket(w_width/2, w_height-30)

def setup ():
    size(w_width, w_height)
    background(127)

def draw ():
    background(127)
    r1.show()
```

`Rockets` tab

```py
class Rocket(object): #I'm not sure if i must put (object) or not, just saw that in tutorials 

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.hgt = 30
        self.wdt = 10


    def show (self):

        rectMode(CENTER)
        stroke(255)
        strokeWeight(2)
        fill(0, 127)
        rect(self.x, self.y, self.wdt, self.hgt)
```

Comment: What exactly are you calling a tab? A `.py` file?

Comment: It's in Processing.py, you can create tabs. But yes it's a .py file

Comment: But what exactly is a "tab"?

Comment: Why be intentionally dense? told you it is a .py file. To make a new .py file in processing you click "New Tab" so it is completely correct to refer to the file like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skip the base class `(object)` in the class declaration. `Rocket` is not inherited from any other object at the moment (see [Inheritance](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance)).

<s>`class Rocket(object):`</s>
`class Rocket:`

And us the `Rockets` (module) namespace:

```py
import Rockets

w_width = 800
w_height = 900
r1 = Rockets.Rocket(w_width/2, w_height-30)
```

or use a *import-from* statement (see [Importing * From a Package](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)):

```py
from Rockets import *

w_width = 800
w_height = 900
r1 = Rocket(w_width/2, w_height-30)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot . i tought i tried that but apparently not.